# Setting up the configuration of Maven and Ant in environment variables

Tags: java, apache, maven, ant, environment-variables

I have configured Maven in an environment variable and checked it in the command prompt and it works. Then I setup and configured Ant in environment variables and checked it in the command prompt and it works but Maven is not working. The problem I found out is the `Path` variable name. I only can set either one of them. How should I configure my environment to make sure both Maven and Ant are working at the same time?

Variable name: Path

Variable value: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-ant-1.9.6\bin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what's happening here is that you aren't using:

1. [a path separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227925/path-separator-for-windows-and-unix) in your `PATH` environment variable (for Windows it's a semi-colon).
2. [quotation marks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851012/set-a-path-variable-with-spaces-in-the-path-in-a-windows-cmd-file-or-batch-file) when your paths have spaces.

Bad:

```
Path Variable value: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-ant-1.9.6\bin
```

Good:

```
PATH="C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin";"C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-ant-1.9.6\bin"
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Its works. Silly mistake by me. really appreciate that. Thanks