# File not found but file exist in directory

Tags: python

I am trying to run the following code on ubuntu but getting file not found error. But same code is working fine on my windows machine

```
...
for elem in items['stats']:
        f = open(r"\root\bot_python\list.txt", "r+")
...
```

Comment: In your own words, what do you expect the `\`s to mean on ubuntu?

Comment: You should use forward slashes as the separator in any literal paths, even on Windows. Python will translate for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the path separator is different between Ubuntu and Windows. See [Path separator for Windows and Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227925/path-separator-for-windows-and-unix) and [separator for both Linux and Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16010992/how-to-use-directory-separator-in-both-linux-and-windows-in-python). For python, you could use [os.path.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to parse your file path before reading it. Btw, [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) is also a good option if you're familiar with some object-oriented concepts.

Answer (score 1):

You should use double back slash instead of single. Like this:

```
...
for elem in items['stats']:
        f = open(r"\\root\\bot_python\\list.txt", "r+")
...
```

Comment: Double backslashes in a raw string are litteral double backslashes. Linux paths don't use backslashes at all. So no, you definitely don't want to use double backslashes here.

Answer (score -2):

I think you need root permission to access the file see you are trying to access a file inside root directory...
Try Running the python script with "sudo python file_name.py"
Maybe it solves your issue.
And use backward slashes for spaces whenever possible.