# Issue while executing get-acl for remote servers

Tags: powershell

I am having the below code to get the data from remote servers. thanks to @Santiago Squarzon

```
$serverlist = Get-Content -Path "C:\ServerList.txt"

# Collect results here
$result = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $serverlist -ScriptBlock {
    $paths_list = $env:Path -Split [System.IO.Path]::PathSeparator
    foreach($sys_Path in $paths_list)
    {
        $Permissions = (Get-Acl -Path $sys_Path).Access
        foreach($acl in $Permissions)
        {
            if(-not $acl.IdentityReference)
            {
                continue
            }   

            [pscustomobject]@{
                ComputerName     = $env:ComputerName
                SystemFolderPath = $sys_Path
                IdenityReference = $acl.IdentityReference.Value
                FileSystemRights = $acl.FileSystemRights
            }
        }
    }
} -HideComputerName

$result | Export-Csv -Path "C:\status_report.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

But I am getting below error while executing it

```
Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Path'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or
empty, and then try the command again.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-Acl], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetAclCommand
    + PSComputerName
```

Please let me know on this.

Comment: Could it be that `$env:Path` contains an empty path (like two `;;` with no content)?

Comment: Try with `$paths_list = $env:Path -Split [System.IO.Path]::PathSeparator -ne ''`. I'm wondering if this happens on all servers or only one. And if it's only one, does the `$env:Path` variable on that server look ok?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon: for the first server itself I am facing this issue. have to check for rest. $env:Path is fine. values are as expected

Comment: Are these servers all Windows based? I believe for Windows the separator to use is the semi-colon `;`, but in linux it apparently is the colon `:` (found that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2228021/9898643))

Comment: To be on the safe side, do `$paths_list = $env:Path -split [System.IO.Path]::PathSeparator | Where-Object { $_ -match '\S' }`, so you can be certain there are no empty or whitespace-only elements in your array

Comment: @Theo I learnt that too a few days ago, that's why I started using `[System.IO.Path]::PathSeparator` hehe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might adding the following check before `$Permissions = (Get-Acl -Path $sys_Path).Access` would resolve the issue:

```
if (($sys_Path -eq $null) -or ($sys_Path -eq '') ) {
    continue
}
```

Comment: You can put both conditions in one: `if([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($sys_Path)){..}` :)