# Adding Java .class to Kotlin compilation

Tags: java, kotlin

Hello people from stackoverflow. I've been struggling to add a compiled java .class to Kotlin compilation. So far,  I've tried:

```
 kotlinc -cp /home/erobless14/Documents/ComputerScience/Languages/Kotlin/learningKotlin/src/oo  generics.kt covariance.kt -include-runtime -d out/cova.jar
```

And I'm getting:

```
covariance.kt:39:20: error: unresolved reference: JavaTimeSeries
    val chartData: JavaTimeSeries<Person> = JavaTimeSeries()
                   ^
covariance.kt:39:45: error: unresolved reference: JavaTimeSeries
    val chartData: JavaTimeSeries<Person> = JavaTimeSeries()
```

JavaTimeSeries is the .class file that is being added as classpath files.

The .class file and the .kt files are located at the same package and same directory.

Do you know what's wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `.class` files to the `-cp` option as a "path": in other words use the [path separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227925/path-separator-for-windows-and-unix) between the full filenames to make one long argument.

Assuming you are on a Unix-based operating system (replace the `:` with `;` for Windows):

```
 kotlinc -cp /home/erobless14/Documents/ComputerScience/Languages/Kotlin/learningKotlin/src/oo/generics.kt:/home/erobless14/Documents/ComputerScience/Languages/Kotlin/learningKotlin/src/oo/covariance.kt -include-runtime -d out/cova.jar
```